# Estimating numbers of births and deaths in a birth death process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, birth-death-process

Given a birth-death process which ends up with a given population size m after a certain time t, I am estimating the size of the population n before this by exponentiating the Q matrix of the corresponding CTMC to find the probabilities of reaching m after time t from various starting points.

After estimating this earlier population size n, I want to estimate how many of those n members of that population have survived to be part of the current population of size m.

How could I go about making this estimation?